# Android scaling popup window

Tags: android, user-interface, popup

i am writing a simple 2D Android Game (sort of puzzles). A user is drawing lines during the game and that is why I decided to an approach in which i resize in runtime to scale correctly on differrent devices. I prepared graphics for 1280x720 and I simply resize them in runtime inside:

```
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {

    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

    if (hasFocus) {
        FrameLayout container = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.main);
        LinearLayout mainView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_main_view);
        TransformationOld transform = new TransformationOld();
        transform.scaleViewToFitInContainerIsotropically(container, mainView);
    }
}
```

The inspiration comes from: http://www.vanteon.com/downloads/Scaling_Android_Apps_White_Paper.pdf

It works fine for Activities, but I cannot have it working for popups.
The way I create popups:

```
public void onClickButtonMainAbout(View view) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) MainActivity.this
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View popupView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_about_backup_with_pixels, null, false);
    final PopupWindow pw = new PopupWindow(popupView, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    pw.showAtLocation(popupView, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

    Button button_ok = (Button) popupView.findViewById(R.id.about_button_ok);
    button_ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            pw.dismiss();
        }
    });

}
```

The popup in xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/popup_about2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/popup_about_main_view2">

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"

...
...
```

Any hints how to have such scaling working for popups to? Now it is simply displayed in 1280x720. I would be thankful for any advice.

Comment: Watch out with resources like this. Quote from said whitepaper "Second, if you want to support devices running Android versions prior to 3.2 (at the time of writing, this is virtually every Android device – see [5])" That means that paper must be nearly 5 years old. I'm not convinced that there are exist no 'Androidesque' ways to accomplish this.

Comment: i noticed that i could set a onWindowFocusChanged listener on popupView, but i do not know how to combine all of this together...